# Inserting select box columns from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Retrieving a table from database. No problem with that. But two columns of that table, I want to retrieve those with select box.

I tried like this. But still seeing two separated columns.
Here it is:

My columns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vMug.jpg

My view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXkCn.jpg

also jquery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU79y.jpg

Comment: This is quite unclear. What's exactly what you want ? Be able to filter your output using selects like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) ?

Comment: you see, i have two select on that TH. I want each one of select show in database table's column. "old_price" and "price"

Comment: Tell us which input will cause you to show which output, otherwise this is just a ramble

Comment: So you want to swap what the column is showing ? Just add the two columns in the output and toggle them with js

Comment: i am retrieving data from database in "td" no prob with that. I have two columns in database price and old price i want to retrive those in view on just one column. Not two separete columns. That s why i added select box. Table header and want to retrieve two column from database in one column in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your two columns to the view and toggle them with js, otherwise you'll have to fetch the whole thing each time via ajax. Here's a jQuery solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pricetag').on('change', function() {
    // Sync select values on toggle  
    $('.pricetag').val($(this).val())
    // Swap hidden columns
    $('tr td:nth-of-type(2), tr td:nth-of-type(3), th:nth-of-type(2), th:nth-of-type(3)').toggleClass('price-hidden')
  })
});
```

```css
.price-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>
      <select name="price" class="pricetag">
        <option value="price">price</option>
        <option value="old">old price</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th class="price-hidden">
      <select name="price" class="pricetag">
        <option value="price">price</option>
        <option value="old">old price</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td class="price-hidden">Old price</td>
      <td>New price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td class="price-hidden">Old price</td>
      <td>New price</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation mate, I tried to what you said but still seing separated columns. I updated my question to explain how I did it? Do i missing something. Also I added the css code into the css file.

Comment: yeah, unhide them that's my mistake. and i editted the column numbers. but still separated. Do I calling wrong js? https://imgur.com/a/RixgCaX

Comment: I call it from folder now https://imgur.com/a/I2BROH8 but still they both show. what do you mean by saying wrap the script in $.ready ? :) sorry for the burden mate, but u really saving me now.

Comment: @KubilayTurgut updated answer, but if they both show, that's a css issue.

Comment: @KubilayTurgut you'll have to figure it out... provided code works.

Comment: I did it mate, thanks you. You were damn right about css.

Answer (score 0):

- Retrieve all columns from database and do coding in your view to
  show all columns
- Using JQuery set a value of drop down in your header and hide related column at page load
- Make a JQuery function to show/hide the columns of the table on the dropdown option select

Let me know if you understand or require a sample code.